# Regular expression is fetching 9 values how can we add all 9 value to next request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Regular expression is fetching 9 values 
Need to add all these ticked values with comma separation in next request.How can we do this in J meter
How can we pass multiple values extracted via regular expression to next request in JMeter
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share some snippet of the HTML response, I'd like to help you with the answer. Also, at times, using an XPath expression in an XPath Extractor can be easier to work with.

If the reference name for is set to VALUE, then you can access each of the 9 matched values as VALUE_1, VALUE_2, ...... VALUE_9

Answer (score 0):

Given you configure your [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as follows:

- Reference Name: `arg_name`
- Regular Expression: `arg_names" value="(.+?)"
- Template: `$1$`
- Match No.: `-1`

You will get [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
arg_name_1=foo
arg_name_2=bar
arg_name_3=baz
arg_name_matchNr=3
```

Now you should be able to concatenate the values using the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(def builder = new StringBuilder(); 1.upto(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("arg_name_matchNr"))) { builder.append(vars.get("arg_name_" + it)).append("\,") }; builder.toString(),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Function Demo]

More information:

- `vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
- [Groovy For Loop Examples](http://grails.asia/groovy-for-loop-examples)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)